# Troubleshooting 'ValueError: time data ... does not match format' when using datetime.strptime

Tags: python, strptime

My input string is `'16-MAR-2010 03:37:04'` and i want to store it as datetime.

I am trying to use:

```
db_inst.HB_Create_Ship_Date = datetime.strptime(fields[7]," %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S ") 
fields[7] = '16-MAR-2010 03:37:04'
```

I am getting an error:

```
::ValueError: time data '16-MAR-2010 03:37:04' does not match format ' %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:
As [John mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460233/datetime-datetime-strptime-problem/2460267#2460267), make it easier on yourself and remove the leading and trailing spaces.

Another thought:
Your current [locale](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) may not specify "MAR" as a month abbreviation.

What does the output of this code give?:

```
import locale
locale.getdefaultlocale()
```

I tested your code on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 9.10, Python 2.6.4) and got the ValueError.
I removed the spaces, changed to non-English locale (Czech), and got the ValueError.

Academic note:
Oddly your code works on Windows XP Python 2.5.5 with the extraneous spaces:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = '16-MAR-2010 03:37:04'
>>> datetime.strptime(dt, " %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S ")
datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 16, 3, 37, 4)
```

Comment: The docs for the locale module mentions """ABMON_1 ... ABMON_12 
Return abbreviated name of the n-th month""" but these (and other useful things) don't seem to exist. Any clues?

Comment: @John:  worked with the leading and trailing spaces on WinXP Python version 2.5.  Just tried on Ubuntu (Python 2.6.4) and got the ValueError.

Comment: Just tried on WHAT version of Python on WHICH manifestation of *nix?

Comment: You are interested in `locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)`, not `getdefaultlocale()` that may be different from the active locale.

Answer (score 2):

Lose the spaces at the front and back of your format. I thought that strptime was documented to vary depending on the whims of whoever wrote the C runtime for your box. However it seems I'm wrong. Which would mean that there's a bug in Python.

Python 2.6.4 on Windows doesn't like leading trailing spaces; see below.

*x users, what do you find?

In the meantime, use the lowest common denominator -- lose the spaces. You may also have a locale problem, as Adam mentioned.

With spaces:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('16-MAR-2010 03:37:04'," %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python26\lib\_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '16-MAR-2010 03:37:04' does not match format ' %d-%b-%Y %H
:%M:%S '
```

Without spaces:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('16-MAR-2010 03:37:04',"%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 16, 3, 37, 4)
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format string has a leading space and a trailing space, but your input string does not.  Remove the space after the starting quotation mark and before the ending quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db_inst.HB_Create_Ship_Date = datetime.strptime(fields[7],"%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Also, have a [look here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) as a reference for DateTime formatting in Python.